# Where to find a documented reference for Test.testSandboxPostCopyScript

Tags: apex, unit-test, sandbox

I'm looking at the `SandboxPostCopy` interface for creating a sandbox post copy script. I found the [Salesforce documentation covering the interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm) and even an example (albeit, syntactically incorrect) of how to test this class.

However, what I cannot seem to find is any documentation on what `Test.testSandboxPostCopyScript` is. I presume this is an undocumented method on the [Test class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm). I have found lots of examples of folks using it in their test classes in forums and blogs, but Salesforce doesn't appear to have any documented reference to this method.

Does anyone know what the signature(s) of this method is(are) and what it is supposed to do?

Also, it is coincidence that the method I'm asking about (line 6 in below example) has the *same* name as the test class' test method (line 4 in below example)?

Here's the Salesforce *official* test class example:

```
@isTest
class testHelloWorld{
@isTest
static void testSandboxPostCopyScript() {
HelloWorld apexclass = new HelloWorld();
Test.testSandboxPostCopyScript(apexClassName, 'orgID', 'sandboxID', 'sandboxName');
System.assertEquals(1,1,'Test something');
```

Comment: Yea, it just a method to mock test the interface that is implemented. Documentation is just not updated to include it i would assume.